# Terminal isn't recognizing any commands in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, git

I installed Git with the [Git installer for OS X](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) and restarted terminal, but I got a "command not found" error. I also installed Meteor (a web development framework) and ran it – I also get a "command not found".

They were working earlier.

The output of `/bin/echo $PATH` is

```
/usr/local/bin
```

This is a fresh install of OS X. Other commands are working though: I think I can `cd` around and `rm` and create files.

Comment: How did you install git? What, precisely, did you enter before it didn't work anymore? What commands don't work? Just `git`, or all? What's the output of `/bin/echo $PATH`?

Comment: I added the info above, could you give me some other commands I could test?

Comment: Run `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` as a temporary fix. If this happens with all Terminal windows you open, you broke one of your shell initialization files (e.g. `.bash_profile`). Look for lines containing `PATH` and edit or remove them.

Comment: By the way, recent versions of OS X comes with `git` out of the box.

Comment: That didnt work, I cant even run open ~/.bash_profile I think I might just reinstall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Fixing your PATH, temporarily

If your path is screwed up, as a temporary fix you can run the following to reset it, like Daniel Beck said:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Now, all commands in your current shell should run as usual. If not, try `hash -r` (in Bash) to rehash the contents of your PATH directories.

#### Finding the problem's cause

You can then try to trace down the error. Since the Git installer only adds its path to `/etc/paths.d`, it's not likely that this caused your shell to malfunction. It's probably a line with `PATH=` in one of your shell's configuration file.

For Bash on OS X, the config files are typically one of the following:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`

You can edit these files with `open -e ~/.bash_profile`, for example. If `open` still isn't recognized, run it with its full path, i.e. `/usr/bin/open -e ~/.bash_profile`. Look for a line that assigns the `PATH`, and remove it. Save the file, and open a new shell to see if it worked.

<sub>Since a login shell is started with the Terminal in OS X (instead of a non-login shell like in many other Linux/Unix variants), it's unlikely that `~/.bashrc` is compromised.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up restoring the machine before I got this answer.